# Sending email with Amazon SES, SMS gateway mangles ReturnPath header into From field

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, sms, hex, amazon-ses

I am using the SES email library from amazon to send text messages by sending them through `5556665555@vtext.com` for example, or just an email itself. However, recently some of the text messages have headers that show the from address as something like this:
`0000013a94c84b04-4f0a3d49-483f-4dfb-8b8c-87a33698a35f-000000@amazonses.com` even though the same email ends up in my email with regular from address. What could be the culprit/solution? This had worked fine previously with no change to how headers are dealt with ( I am using amazons SES library and haven't mucked with internals). The code is the exact same when I send it to a regular email address or an SMS gateway address.

UPDATE

I have realized that vtext changes from address to the ReturnPath Header, giving me the long drawn out address. I have tried setting the opt variable to contain `'ReturnPath', 'me@me.com'` so when I call `$ses->send_email($this->source,$this->destination,$this->message,$this->opt);` it does pass it in, however, this is being ignored anyways. How can I force SES to respect the ReturnPath header, or alternatively, have the correct From address show up.

What is troubling is that ReturnPath is used for bounce reporting, so if this hack for verizons broken system is in place, I will no longer receive bounces.. but that is the best I've got at this point.

Comment: ` How can I force SES to respect the ReturnPath header, or alternatively, have the correct From address show up` - Amazon do not get ReturnPath by their rules. Check about it in their rules.

Comment: Hi Sergey, I have not found anything related to them not getting it? Are you saying in essence there is no way to alter this behaviour?

Comment: well, in some how-to amazon says about it - returnpath not accepted. Sorry my english bad. Look in docs sendemail, sendemailraw for accepted headers.